# Attribute Error When Saving Pytorch Model

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to save pytorch model in one .py file and use it in another .py file, but I get
`AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Here is what I have:

train.py

```
data = {
    "model_state": model.state_dict,
    "optimizer_state": optimizer.state_dict,
    "input_size": input_size,
    "output_size": output_size,
    "hidden_size": hidden_size,
    "all_words": all_words,
    "tags": tags
}
file = "data.pth"
torch.save(data, file)
```

use.py

```
file = "data.pth"
data = torch.load(file)
input_size = data['input_size']
output_size = data['output_size']
hidden_size = data['hidden_size']
all_words = data['all_words']
tags = data['tags']
model_state = data['model_state']

model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
model.load_state_dict(model_state)
model.eval()
```

`NeuralNet` is a class I defined elsewhere for building a model. The error happens with the second to last line of use.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, what you have done is save a `function` (AKA method in OOP) then load it in a variable utilizing `deepcopy` which is not available for functions!

The only change you need to make is adding `()` to `state_dict`. Let's assume this is the model

```
import copy
from torch import nn
import torch
class MyModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.layer1=nn.Linear(10,4) 
    self.act1=nn.Sigmoid()
  
  def forward(self,x):
    x=self.layer1(x)
    x=self.act1(x)
    return x
```

type of `state_dict` vs type of `state_dict()`:

```
print('Type With (): ', type(model.state_dict()), '\nType Without (): ', type(model.state_dict))
#Type With ():  <class 'collections.OrderedDict'> 
#Type Without ():  <class 'method'>
```

reproducing the error:

```
model = MyModel()
torch.save(model.state_dict, 'model_state.pth')
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.load_state_dict(copy.deepcopy(torch.load("model_state.pth",device)))
# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

the correct way:

```
model = MyModel()
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'model_state.pth')
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.load_state_dict(copy.deepcopy(torch.load("model_state.pth",device)))
```